# Does P-Factor increase with thrust?

Tags: general-aviation, propeller

I was trying flightgear simulator since I am not a pilot (but have completed ground school) and one thing I have noticed is that the P-Factor increases with thrust applied whether taking off or in cruise flight.

Is this realistic? Does P-Factor vary based on thrust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should. In the end, [p-factor](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/312/whats-p-factor-and-why-does-it-occur) is just a funny word for the out-of-center shift of the thrust vector, and if the vector is larger, the effect should be equally larger.

Answer (score 2):

YES! In fact P -Factor is the asymmetric thrust that the propellers generate at increased AoA(Angles Of Attack). In other words P-factor is the asymmetric disk loading.

[Thrust and P-factor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBX81yLb9I0)

For the majority of single engine aircraft, this  means that the aircraft will yaw to the left at high angles of attack unless an appropriate right rudder alteration is applied.